# Using Consul to monitoring 3rd party services

Tags: spring, apache-zookeeper, microservices, consul

As a organisation, we have 100+ services running at the same time, to keep the company functioning (namely software applications to assists the HR, Finance, Purchasing, Estate, Services, payroll, etc....)

our main focus is to look after the integrations between those services, so they can functioning as a single unit, rather than a list of isolated applications

LDAP, Oracle Database, SOAP webservices, tomcat based webApps are our critical services, we are currently looking at a service monitoring and discovery tool to manage those services

my questions is with our in house webApps or webservices, through the consul java API its fairly easy to register with the Consul server, and implement a health check mechanism. I found its difficult to register and monitoring other services such as LDAP, database or 3rd party SOAP services

anyone can share some examples or point me to the right directions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an external address in your [service definition](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/services.html).  For example, suppose you had an external LDAP server that you wanted to run a TCP check against:

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "ldap",
    "port": 4432,
    "checks": [
      {
        "tcp": "my-ldap.example.org:4432",
        "interval": "10s"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You could then query consul at `ldap.service.consul`.  Be sure to look into prepared queries and the `nearest` attribute.